# EmberJS: can we make a random classnameBinding for each template?

Tags: templates, ember.js

I would like to have random classname on EmberJS Template.

It should look something like in HTML

```
<div classname='rotate-top'>
</div>
<div classname='rotate-bottom'>
</div>
<div classname='rotate-left'>
</div>
```

i try to do in emberjs, it will look like

```
{{#each item in model }}
<div classname='rotate-{{direction}}'>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

direction will be a controller property that will generate random direction. 
However, it doesn't work. Every item will generate the same direction. it is not random.
How can I achieve this trick?

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Controller.extend
   direction: ->
     (random function generate either top, left, right, bottom)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encapsulate the "random" logic in a component.

For example you can create a component that outputs an element with a random class like this

```
App.RandomDirectionComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['direction'],
  direction: function(){
    var directions = ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'];
    return 'rotate-' + directions[Math.floor((Math.random() * 4))];
}.property()
});
```

You would then be able to use the component like

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{#random-direction tagName="li"}}
    {{item}}
  {{/random-direction}}
{{/each}}
```

You can see a working example here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qiqufu/1/edit?html,css,js,output